# rsh Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: kali-linux, rsh

I am trying to use RSH commands using for example: `rsh -l root 10.0.2.5 "ls"`

When I run this command I get

```
getnameinfo: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

but I get a shell by just running `rsh -l root 10.0.2.5`

How do I fix this issue? (I have to use RSH, I am exploiting this service suggesting a switch would defy the point)

Comment: I believe `rsh` needs rDNS working on the target machine

Comment: @roaima its confusing why it needs the rDNS to send a command when I can get a shell :s

Comment: Does `rsh -l root 10.0.2.5 "ls"` always fail and `rsh -l root 10.0.2.5` always work?  Does it matter if you try them the other way around (say with an hour wait in between)?

Comment: @EightBitTony always

Comment: Is this the original `rsh` that trusts the client for "verification" or the one with kerberos added?

Comment: @roaima I just installed from the most recent repos from kali